# Helicity conservation in QED

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, pair-production

In QED, suppose I talk of annihilation of electron and positron, is it right to say that if the electron is right handed then the positron is left handed and so the total $S_z=0$ (Assuming they have zero orbital angular momentum. Also,does the answer change even if they have orbital angular momentum?)?

Comment: In the center of momentum of the collision, where two decay γs are necessitated by E-p conservation, $S_z$ =1 for your choice, but -1 for a left-handed electron annihilating a right-handed positron.

Comment: @CosmasZachos  I didn't get this point completely. As photons have spin1, the total $S_z$ for decay side can be -2,-1,0,1,2. In that case, -1,0,1 can be total $S_z$ in the annihilation side of electron and positron. Now, what prevents $S_z$ = 0 in case I mentioned by assuming $S_z$ = +1/2 for electron (right handed) and -1/2 for positron as it is left handed?(Am I right in equating the left handed positron with S_z= -1/2 as spin and momentum are in opposite direction in this case?)

Comment: No you are not! The e and positron momenta are pointing in the opposite directions, in the center of momentum frame, so the spins are, perforce, pointing in the *same* direction. Diagram it, and apply the rotation matrices to the helicity amplitudes.